# Extract the value of multiple occurred tag in XML

Tags: java, xml

I want to extract the value of a tag, which occur multiple times, recursive or non-recursive in a XML file. How can I do that?

Example:

```
 <title>National Origins of Books</title>
```

I tried using following in Java:

```
jounralNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("title");
Node childNode = (Node) jounralNodeList.item(0).getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < childNode.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++)
        journalName = childNode.getChildNodes().item(i).getTextContent();
```

But that gives me value of the first occurrence only.
If it's easy to do in Python or Ruby, I won't mind.

Comment: Post a minimum sample of the XML at least.

Comment: Try this `    jounralNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("title");
    for (int i = 0; i < jounralNodeList.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++){
        Node childNode = (Node) jounralNodeList.item(i);
        journalName = childNode.getTextContent();
    }`